# detail information about poi point in MKMapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, point-of-interest

In the iOS 8.0 default map application, when you tap the POI point, you get detailed information including the name of the POI and address.

My question is:

1. Is it possible to do the same as this using MKMapView or IOS native code?
2. If not, how can I get the POI data with the map scale (because the POI point shown on the map relies on the region and scale). So, I need to fetch the data to know which POI point shows based on this region and scale.

Answer (score 4):

For get **detailed information including the address of the POI** I think you can do this in two steps:

1. Get the coordinate of your POI
2. Convert them for get address info; see this beautiful example:

   ```
   CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
   CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:32.00 longitude:21.322]; //insert your coordinates

   [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:loc
         completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
            //String to hold address
            NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
            NSLog(@"addressDictionary %@", placemark.addressDictionary);

            NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.region);
            NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.country);  // Give Country Name
            NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.locality); // Extract the city name
            NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.name);
            NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.ocean);
            NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.postalCode);
            NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.subLocality);

            NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.location);
            //Print the location to console
            NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Could not locate");
        }
   ];
   ```

If you need to **center on a region your map** you can do it just like this:

```
- (void)gotoLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;

    newRegion.center.latitude = NY_LATITUDE;
    newRegion.center.longitude = NY_LONGTITUDE;

    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.5f;
    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.5f;

    [self.myMapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
}
```

I hope these code examples can help you :)

For learn more about **MKMapViewClass** (I recommend it) check the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html) or [this beatiful example on how to manage POI with Apple Maps](http://www.myswiftjourney.me/2014/10/23/using-mapkit-mkmapview-how-to-create-a-annotation/).